# Mongoose Find and Update Dynamic Ids

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, updates

The records in my MongoDB is as follows:

{"_id":"User1","_2016":[{"_id":801,"ts":20},{"_id":802,"ts":50}]}

Here 8 indicates Month and 01 indicates date in 801

I receive date dynamically from UI and  based on that I want to update the records.

e.g:
If I recieve User as User1 and Date as 20160801, then I need to find records with _id : User1 and _2016._id : 801.

How the same can be achieved in Mongoose?

then I need to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use

`.find({_id:"User1","_2016._id":801}).exec(callback)`

or

`var obj1 = {_id:"User1"}; var obj2 = {"_2016._id":801}; foo.find(obj1,obj2,(err,doc)=>{ console.log(JSON.stringify(doc)); })`

Comment: Thanks but I want to make the _id:"User1","_2016._id":801 via variables since this depends on incoming data. How can I make it achieve the same via variables as my schema is dynamic?

Comment: You mean like this:? `var obj1 = {_id:"User1"};
var obj2 = {"_2016._id":801};

foo.find(obj1,obj2,(err,doc)=>{
 console.log(JSON.stringify(doc));
})`

Comment: Thanks Ordaz for the pointers. It lead me to good inputs but now I am stuck below while fetching and update:

Comment: Now I am getting error **cannot use the part (_2016 of _2016.id) to traverse the element**                                                                          `var userid = "b9865";
var inputYear = '2016';
var dkey = '_'+inputYear+'._id';
var dval = parseInt('807');
var obj1 = {'_id':userid};
var obj2 = JSON.parse('{"'+dkey+'":'+dval+'}');
var obj3 = JSON.parse('{"$inc":{"_2016.$.tse":2,"_2016.$.tts":100}}');

console.log(obj2);
console.log(obj3);

Model.User.findByIdAndUpdate(obj1,obj2,obj3,function(err,doc){
if(err){
        console.error(err);
}
});`

Comment: I was able to solve it using findOneAndUpdate. Thanks Ordaz for the help. Marked it as an answer